# Agile toolkit atk4 Select Multiple or Listbox field

Tags: select, listbox, field, atk4, agiletoolkit

I am developing a form using Agile toolkit (atk4), I am trying to do Listbox or multiple selection within Field, can you show me example of how i can do it as i couldn't find any control allow me to do muliple selction or listbox with the agile toolkit .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Form/Control/Dropdown and Form/Control/Lookup form fields.

Also you're very welcome to join our Discord channel and I'm sure community will help you in no time.

Also under /demos folder there are a lot of examples and also you can see them here online https://ui.agiletoolkit.org/demos/form/form.php
And all documentation is under /docs folder too.

Comment: 1)  $form->addControl(
    'multi',
    [
        Form\Control\Dropdown::class,
        'caption' => 'Multiple selection',
        'empty' => 'Choose has many options needed',
        'isMultiple' => true,
        'values' => ['default' => 'Default', 'option1' => 'Option 1', 'option2' => 'Option 2'],
    ]
);

Comment: 2)$form->addField('multiSelect', ['caption' => 'multi Selection', 'DropDown', 'values'=> $array,'isMultiple' => true ,'readonly' => $readonly, ['dropdownOptions' => ['fullTextSearch' => true]]]);